# android studio 2.2.2 drawable-hdpi hidden

Tags: android-studio, drawable

I just updated to Android Studio 2.2.2 and, now, my drawable-hdpi folder is merged into drawable. In prior versions, I was able to make them display separately by unchecking "flatten packages" and "compact empty middle packages". No effect this time.

It's making it very hard to navigate to the selector files. I hope there is a way to restore the separation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browse your computer for the image you want to upload to drawable, copy the image and go to your android studio.
right-click drawable and choose paste.
[You will get a pop up prompting you to choose destination directory. Choose drawable-mdpi and click ok. You will then be prompted to give it a new name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQzvI.png)

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't my question. The question is how to get the "project" sidebar to show the subdirectories.

Comment: in android studio 2.2.2, the sub-directories were removed. You can now choose them as destination directories and are visible on every image

Comment: Again, my question is how to get the individual directories to show, not how to work with the dumbed down UI they now provide. If you don't know the answer, that's fine.